# Relation Between NetBIOS and Socket API

Tags: windows, sockets, smb, netbios

From [SuperUser Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/637696/what-is-netbios-does-windows-need-its-ports-137-and-138-open?answertab=votes#tab-top):

> An application that uses the NetBIOS interface API for network communication can be run on any protocol stack that supports a NetBIOS interface.

Can we say that NetBIOS is similar to socket API?

Also what is the relation between SMB and NetBIOS? If NetBIOS is similar to socket API, is it possible to implement SMB in socket API?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we say that NetBIOS is similar to socket API?

Yes both of them are APIs that provides access to networking. They provide functionality for data delivery and session management. The reason why there are two API with the similar functionality is described at a lot places - for example at http://www.mcsecamp.com/MCSE%20Training%20Guide%20TCP%20IP/5a65bdc.htm

> Also what is the relation between SMB and NetBIOS?

SMB is an application layer protocol. The original SMB implementation used NetBIOS API. Nevertheless SMB does not depend on specific API and it can be implemented by any API that provides functions like NetBIOS.

> Is it possible to implement SMB in socket API?

Yes. For example Samba implements SMB and it uses the socket API.